# Mathematical cryptic clues

Tags: word, wordplay, number-sequence, cryptic-clues

> 1. Programming language, after *removing* loss for you, reverses time (6)
> 2. Complex arithmetic begins, Turing *tests* start beforehand (7)
> 3. Quadruply male doctor Einstein, *familiarly* (11)
> 4. Lie on a 100/100 imaginary *item* (9)
> 5. Between 3.14 and *2.718* is originally risky mathematics (5)
> 6. Arctan *maps* every other arccot into an embankment, too (8)
> 7. *Heated* rant with part of Ulam spiral (7)
> 8. Curse without Germain’s initial *initial* (4)

Solve these cryptic clues (no definitions), then find the answer to this question: **what role does math play in our daily lives?**

<sup>*Remember: when in doubt, always consult  [OEIS!](http://oeis.org/)*</sup>

Comment: 5 on the list makes me think of pie.

Comment: @user477343 of course, *you’d* know all about that ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By the time I posted this (in an incomplete state, though it's done now) others had also solved the first 5 clues. I shan't reproduce those solutions here. Here are the last three.

> Arctan maps every other arccot into an embankment, too (8)

> ABUNDANT. (Take the word ARCTAN. Replace RCT, found as alternate letters of ARCCOT, with BUND, a type of embankment. Then add T, which I guess comes from "too" in the clue though I don't quite understand how.)

> Heated rant with part of Ulam spiral (7)

> NATURAL. (Anagram of RANT ULA).

> Curse without Germain’s initial initial (4)

> PELL. (SPELL without the initial letter *Sophie* Germain's first, i.e., initial, name.)

So, what's next? Well,

> all the answers are names of particular sets/sequences of integers, and the question directs us to OEIS. And of course we have those *italicized* words. I confess that before doing what I'm about to describe I tried a couple of other things that incorporated most of the right ideas "but not necessarily in the right order"; a helpful hint from OP in the comments set me on the right track. So: take the position of the italicized word in each clue, and use it to index into the corresponding sequence of numbers. In some cases there's more than one possible convention as to where to start; following the advice in the puzzle we'll use the version in OEIS. We get (SQUARE:4) 9, (CATALAN:5) 14, (TETRAHEDRAL:5) 20, (FIBONACCI:6) 5, (PRIME:4) 7, (ABUNDANT:2) 18, (NATURAL:1) 1, (PELL:5) 12, mapping via A1Z26 to letters I N T E G R A L.

So clearly the answer is, appropriately enough, that

> mathematics is **integral** to our daily lives.

Comment: The two cryptic clues you got are right!

Comment: Very good! My best for clue 6 was COSECANT but too loose a fit.

Comment: Awesome, you answered the question correctly! Regarding the “too,” rot13(V arrqrq n jnl gb pyhr n G, naq nyy V pbhyq guvax bs gb nppbzcyvfu gung jnf gung jbeq, juvpu vf n ovg vssl ohg V pbhyqa’g guvax bs nalguvat orggre). Your green check mark will arrive within 1-2 business days :)

Answer (score 11):

No time to finish, but a partial...

2. Complex arithmetic begins, Turing *tests* start beforehand (7)

> C(omplex) + A(rithmetics) + T(ests) + ALAN (Turing) = **CATALAN**

3. Quadruply male doctor Einstein, *familiarly* (11)

> TETRA (quadruply) + HE + DR + AL(bert) = **TETRAHEDRAL**

4. Lie on a 100/100 imaginary *item* (9)

> FIB (lie) ON A C/C (100/100) I (imaginary item) = **FIBONACCI**

5. Between 3.14 and *2.718* is originally risky mathematics (5)

> PI (3.14) + E (2.178) with R(isky) M(athematics) inside = **PRIME**

Comment: These are all correct!

Answer (score 8):

Adding to answer by @jafe

1. Programming language, after removing loss for you, reverses time (6)

> SQ <strike>L</strike> (replaced by) U (you) + ARE (era reversed) = **SQUARE**

Comment: Yep, that’s the one!